# Close popover by clicking UIButton in popover that created from program

Tags: ios, storyboard, popover, pass-data

I have a UIButton in tableViewCell that perform

```
-(IBAction)buttonClicked:(id)sender{

UIStoryboard *SB = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"ABC" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *VC = [SB instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"someID"];

popoverController  = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:VC];
[popoverController setDelegate:self];

..............................

[popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:rect
                                       inView:self.view
                     permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionRight
                                     animated:YES];
}
```

to popover a controller which consist of a UITextField and a UIButton. Now I'm going to pass back the string in UITextField from the popover controller by clicking the UIButton?

Comment: zWhat is your requirement? You want to pass the text or close popover?

Answer (score 0):

retain this view controller in in .h

```
UIViewController *VC;
```

change this

```
UIViewController *VC = [SB instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"someID"];
```

to

```
self.VC = [SB instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"someID"];
```

It will be deallocated from the memory when the .h object destroyed from memory.

When you dismiss the popover, still the last popover exists and you can access like

```
VC.yourTextField.text
```

When you present again on popover make sure to empty the text field to empty by setting @"".

Comment: I add retain the VC in .h and synthesis it in .m. 
However VC.yourTextView didn't appear. Is there any other method for example pass delegate backward?

Comment: add yourTextView inside VC.h

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a TableView with your custom TableViewCell you can create a method in your TableViewCell class for when you push your button:

CustomTableViewCell.h

```
@interface CustomTableViewCell : UITableViewCell

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIButton *cellButton;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITextField *cellTextField;

- (NSString*)getText;

@end
```

CustomTableViewCell.m

```
- (NSString*)getText {

    return self.cellTextField.text;
}
```

And in your CustomTableView class:

CustomTableView.m

in delegate method of your CustomTableView set self as delegate to your CustomTableViewCell

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    CustomTableViewCell *cellCustom = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CustomTableViewCell"];
    ...
    [cellCustom.cellButton setTag:indexPath.row];
    ...
    return cell;
}
```

And finally in your IBAction method of your button:

```
- (IBAction)pushButton:(id)sender{

    UIButton *btn = (UIButton*)sender;

    CustomTableViewCell *cellSelected = (CustomTableViewCell *)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:btn.tag];

    NSString *strWritten = [cellSelected getText];

    NSLog(@"Text written: %@", strWritten);
}
```